# Code to estimate an OLS fixed effects dummy variable in R

Tags: model, linear-regression, fixed, effects, dummy-variable

I am looking for a command (not the total code) to estimate an OLS fixed effects dummy variable model that includes a fixed effect for each state in my data frame (balanced panel dataset).

My data frame includes states, years, and multiple independent variables I would like to include.

Kind regards,

QIA-man

Comment: StackOverflow is a Question and Answer site, not a "Please code this for me" site.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer to your question:

```
model <- felm(y ~ x1 + x2 + xn | factor(xfixedeffects) , data = df)
```

Comment: Hey, idefinitelydonotknowQIA-man. I don't get any fixed effects per state?